# Не работает вк апи если делаю редирект на сайт

Tags: php, веб-программирование, vkontakte-api, веб-сервер

Вопрос такой почему появляется такая ошибка

```html
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"standalone applications should use blank.html as redirect_uri to access messages"}
```

Выполняю такой запрос

```html
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=000XXX&scope=notify,photos,friends,audio,video,notes,pages,docs,status,questions,offers,wall,groups,messages,notifications,stats,ads,offline&redirect_uri=https://2oq.ru/005/index.php&display=page&response_type=token
```

если делать редирект на вк апи то норм но как сделать редирект себе на сервер
апи открытый написаны одинаково со ссылкой на директорию

Comment: Ты ещё должен редирект в белый список добавить в настройках приложения вк

Comment: В тексте ошибки содержится ответ на вопрос, не?

Comment: @andreymal  проблема такая сейчас и токен есть но если я использую адрес вк то метод выводит данные то есть делаю на прямую через браузер, а если через сайт то ничего не возращает

Comment: php - это **не Standalone**.......Standalone - это когда android/ios/winphone/windowsPC......вот там как раз и есть blank.html....... + `messages` и `audio` доступен только в standalone и возможно он выбивает ошибку (если в настройках все же выбран пункт веб приложение)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала пишем

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=***&display=page&redirect_uri=https://2oq.ru/8455/index.php&scope=friends&response_type=code&v=5.69
```

потом в строке браузера появится

```
ваш домен code ****
```

то чему ровняется коде вставляем результат

```
https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=***&scope=notify,photos,friends,audio,video,notes,pages,docs,status,questions,offers,wall,groups,messages,notifications,stats,ads,offline&client_secret=***&redirect_uri=https://2oq.ru/***/index.php&code=****
```

потом появится токен

[Документация](https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user)

Comment: Код в сниппеты вставлять стоит только если в них что-то выполняется. В других случаях это излишне

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский просто хотел помочь тема злободневная, ответ вроде прост а толкового ответа не на одном форуме нет

Comment: Я же не упрекаю  в чем то, а объясняю как лучше делать....А по поводу ответа - на самом деле всего-то и нужно что внимательно прочитать документацию, поэтому о какой злободневности идет речь - совсем непонятно